"❗️[Error]: Webhook handler for Stripe event of type [checkout.session.completed] failed: User not found!"
Estoy intentando integrar stripe con firebase, y a la hora de hacer los test con la CLI de stripe todo correcto, esta es la salida,
 2024-07-18 13:18:00   --> payment_intent.created [evt_3PdsLjKqN4uFWdKyHCf14hgPjPQ]
2024-07-18 13:18:01  <--  [200] POST http://localhost:8080/api/webhook [evt_3PdsLjKqN4uKyHCf14hgPjPQ]
2024-07-18 13:18:17   --> customer.created [evt_1PdsM0KqNwfde4uKyHCfdzV1SfTH]
2024-07-18 13:18:17   --> payment_intent.succeeded [evt_3PdsLjKfweqN4uKyHCf1zZCDvs2]
2024-07-18 13:18:17  <--  [200] POST http://localhost:8080/api/webhook [evt_1PdsM0KqN4uKyHCfdzV1SfTH]
2024-07-18 13:18:17   --> charge.succeeded [evt_3PdsLjKqNFF4uKyHCf1p6hnuWj]
2024-07-18 13:18:17   --> checkout.session.completed [evt_1P7245dsM0KqN4uKyHCflPwawoPc]
2024-07-18 13:18:17  <--  [200] POST http://localhost:8080/api/webhook [evt_3PdsLjKqN4uKyHCf1zZCDvs2]
2024-07-18 13:18:17  <--  [200] POST http://localhost:8080/api/webhook [evt_3PdsLjKqN4uKyHCf1p6hnuWj]
2024-07-18 13:18:19  <--  [200] POST http://localhost:8080/api/webhook [evt_1PdsM0KqN4uKyHCflPwawoPc]
2024-07-18 13:19:41   --> payment_intent.created [evt_3PdsNLFAKqN4uKyHCf05jc5QfK]
2024-07-18 13:19:41  <--  [200] POST http://localhost:8080/api/webhook [evt_3PdsNLKqN4uKyDFHCf05jc5QfK]


pero cuando cambio la api key de test por la de producción y realizo un pago me sale esto en el Dashboard de Stripe
checkout.session.completed

More options
Respuesta
Código de estado de HTTP
200 (OK)
{
  "error": "Webhook handler failed. View function logs in Firebase."
}

y cuando miro en firebase me sale lo siguiente
"❗️[Error]: Webhook handler for  Stripe event [evt_1PdsB7KqN4udQKyHCf0F8hUbXi] of type [checkout.session.completed] failed: User not found!"

pero stripe me cobro correctamente y en modo test el campo de firebase que maneja la suscripcion se actualiza correctamente, es decir que si que encuentra el usuario en modo test, no se porque esta pasando esto ni a que se debe.
Este es el codigo que maneja los webhooks
import os
import logging
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pytz
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, g
from flask_cors import CORS
import stripe
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore, auth

# Cargar las variables de entorno desde el archivo .env
load_dotenv()

# Configurar los registros de la aplicación
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

# Inicializar Firebase Admin SDK
try:
    cred = credentials.ApplicationDefault()
    firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
        'projectId': '6FDS84fr1WD4SF6a'
    })
except Exception as e:
    logging.error(f'Error al inicializar Firebase Admin SDK: {e}')
    raise

# Configurar la clave secreta de Stripe
stripe.api_key = os.getenv('STRIPE_API_KEY')
stripe_webhook_secret = os.getenv('STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET')

if not stripe.api_key or not stripe_webhook_secret:
    logging.error('Las claves de Stripe no están configuradas correctamente en el archivo .env')
    raise EnvironmentError('Faltan las claves de Stripe en el archivo .env')

# Configurar la aplicación Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": "*"}})

# Middleware para obtener el ID de usuario autenticado en Firebase
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.user_id = None  # Inicializamos g.user_id como None por defecto
    try:
        # Verificamos el token de Firebase que viene en el header Authorization
        authorization_header = request.headers.get('Authorization')
        if authorization_header:
            id_token = authorization_header.split('Bearer ')[1]
            decoded_token = auth.verify_id_token(id_token)
            g.user_id = decoded_token.get('uid')
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f'Error al verificar el token de Firebase: {e}')

# Manejador de ruta para el webhook de Stripe
@app.route('/api/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def handle_stripe_webhook():
    payload = request.get_data(as_text=True)
    sig_header = request.headers.get('Stripe-Signature')

    if not sig_header:
        logging.error('No se encontró la cabecera de la firma')
        return jsonify({'error': 'Falta la firma'}), 400

    try:
        event = stripe.Webhook.construct_event(
            payload=payload, sig_header=sig_header, secret=stripe_webhook_secret
        )
    except (ValueError, stripe.error.SignatureVerificationError) as e:
        logging.error(f'Error al verificar el webhook: {e}')
        return jsonify({'error': 'Verificación fallida'}), 400

    logging.debug('Evento verificado: %s', event)
    db = firestore.client()

    def update_user_subscription(user_id, subscription_days):
        user_ref = db.collection('users').document(user_id)
        user_doc = user_ref.get()

        if not user_doc.exists:
            logging.error('Usuario no encontrado: %s', user_id)
            return jsonify({'error': 'Usuario no encontrado'}), 404

        trial_end_date = user_doc.get('trialEndDate')
        if not trial_end_date:
            logging.error('Fecha de finalización de la prueba no encontrada para el usuario %s', user_id)
            return jsonify({'error': 'Fecha de finalización de la prueba no encontrada'}), 400

        trial_end_datetime = trial_end_date if isinstance(trial_end_date, datetime) else trial_end_date.to_pydatetime()
        now = datetime.now(pytz.utc)
        effective_date = max(trial_end_datetime, now)
        new_end_datetime = effective_date + timedelta(days=subscription_days)
        new_end_datetime = new_end_datetime.astimezone(pytz.utc)

        user_ref.update({'trialEndDate': new_end_datetime})
        logging.debug('Suscripción actualizada correctamente para el usuario %s', user_id)
        return jsonify({'message': 'Éxito'}), 200

    def handle_checkout_session_completed(session):
        user_id = session['metadata'].get('firebaseUID')
        subscription_days = session['metadata'].get('subscriptionDays')

        logging.debug(f'Datos de la sesión: {session}')

        if not user_id or not subscription_days:
            logging.error('Datos de la sesión incompletos: user_id: %s, subscription_days: %s', user_id, subscription_days)
            return jsonify({'error': 'Datos de la sesión incompletos'}), 400

        try:
            subscription_days = int(subscription_days)
        except ValueError:
            logging.error('subscriptionDays no es un entero válido: %s', subscription_days)
            return jsonify({'error': 'subscriptionDays no es un entero válido'}), 400

        db = firestore.client()
        user_ref = db.collection('users').document(user_id)
        user_doc = user_ref.get()

        if not user_doc.exists:
            logging.error('Usuario no encontrado en Firebase: %s', user_id)
            return jsonify({'error': 'Usuario no encontrado'}), 404

        try:
            trial_end_date = user_doc.get('trialEndDate')
            if not trial_end_date:
                logging.error('Fecha de finalización de la prueba no encontrada para el usuario %s', user_id)
                return jsonify({'error': 'Fecha de finalización de la prueba no encontrada'}), 400

            trial_end_datetime = trial_end_date if isinstance(trial_end_date, datetime) else trial_end_date.to_pydatetime()
            now = datetime.now(pytz.utc)
            effective_date = max(trial_end_datetime, now)
            new_end_datetime = effective_date + timedelta(days=subscription_days)
            new_end_datetime = new_end_datetime.astimezone(pytz.utc)

            user_ref.update({'trialEndDate': new_end_datetime})
            logging.debug('Suscripción actualizada correctamente para el usuario %s', user_id)
            return jsonify({'message': 'Éxito'}), 200

        except Exception as e:
            logging.error('Error al actualizar la suscripción para el usuario %s: %s', user_id, e)
            return jsonify({'error': 'Error interno del servidor'}), 500

    def handle_payment_intent_created(payment_intent):
        logging.info(f'PaymentIntent creado: {payment_intent["id"]}')
        # Lógica adicional para manejar la creación de PaymentIntent
        return jsonify({'message': 'PaymentIntent creado'}), 200

    def handle_customer_created(customer):
        logging.info(f'Cliente creado: {customer["id"]}')
        # Lógica adicional para manejar la creación de Customer
        return jsonify({'message': 'Cliente creado'}), 200

    def handle_payment_intent_succeeded(payment_intent):
        logging.info(f'PaymentIntent exitoso: {payment_intent["id"]}')
        # Lógica adicional para manejar el éxito de PaymentIntent
        return jsonify({'message': 'PaymentIntent exitoso'}), 200

    def handle_charge_succeeded(charge):
        logging.info(f'Cobro exitoso: {charge["id"]}')
        # Lógica adicional para manejar el éxito de Charge
        return jsonify({'message': 'Cobro exitoso'}), 200

    try:
        if event['type'] == 'checkout.session.completed':
            return handle_checkout_session_completed(event['data']['object'])
        elif event['type'] == 'payment_intent.created':
            return handle_payment_intent_created(event['data']['object'])
        elif event['type'] == 'customer.created':
            return handle_customer_created(event['data']['object'])
        elif event['type'] == 'payment_intent.succeeded':
            return handle_payment_intent_succeeded(event['data']['object'])
        elif event['type'] == 'charge.succeeded':
            return handle_charge_succeeded(event['data']['object'])
        else:
            logging.info('Evento no manejado: %s', event['type'])
            return jsonify({'message': 'Evento no manejado'}), 200

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error('Error procesando el evento: %s', e)
        return jsonify({'error': 'Error interno del servidor'}), 500

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=8080)


y esta es la creacion del pago
Future<void> _launchStripePayment(BuildContext context, int days, String userId) async {
  try {
    // Definir el monto del pago en centavos de euro
    int unitAmount = days == 30 ? 50 : 3630; // 0.50 euros por 30 días o 36.30 euros por año

    // Crear una sesión de pago de Stripe
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('https://api.stripe.com/v1/checkout/sessions'),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer rk_live_51Ko8SeKqN4uKyHCfShe7HpPlL1PIhR1ILY5AubJ7bKASAS3AETHGDEZFRC6481163DVCAFRaWRhE6FSB6
ExkPz04nq2J0zhNX85IzIcmBGcCLbAHcKNx1Ok40hIHV7K00DWgtLFEb',
      },
      body: {
        'payment_method_types[]': 'card',
        'line_items[0][price_data][currency]': 'eur',
        'line_items[0][price_data][product_data][name]': 'Subscription',
        'line_items[0][price_data][unit_amount]': unitAmount.toString(),
        'line_items[0][quantity]': '1',
        'mode': 'payment',
        'success_url': 'https://www.peopletimesport.com/',
        'cancel_url': 'https://www.peopletimesport.com/',
        'metadata[firebaseUID]': userId,
        'metadata[subscriptionDays]': days.toString(),
      }
    );

    // Decodificar la respuesta de Stripe
    final sessionData = json.decode(response.body);
    final url = sessionData['url'];

    // Abrir la URL de pago en un navegador web
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);

      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text('Payment session initiated'),
          duration: Duration(seconds: 4),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      await FlutterWebBrowser.openWebPage(
        url: url,
        customTabsOptions: CustomTabsOptions(
          colorScheme: CustomTabsColorScheme.dark,
          instantAppsEnabled: true,
          showTitle: true,
          urlBarHidingEnabled: true,
        ),
      );
    }
  } catch (e) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: Text('Error opening link: $e'),
        duration: Duration(seconds: 4),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Necesito que el encuentre el usuario para poder actualizar su suscripción.
